# Need to read the values of a config file from a shell script

Tags: shell, configuration-files

I have a shell script and a common configuration file where all the generic path, username and other values are stored. I want to get the value from this configuration file while I am running the sh script.

example:

```
sample.conf
pt_user_name=>xxxx
pt_passwd=>Junly@2014
jrnl_source_folder=>x/y/v
pt_source_folder=>/x/y/r/g
css_source_folder=>/home/d/g/h
```

Now i want get some thing like this in my sh script.

```
cd $css_source_folder
```

this command inside the shell script should take me to the location d/g/h while the script is running.

Is there any way to achieve this other than with grep and awk??

Thanks
Rinu

Comment: Can you use `cut` and `paste` ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read from conf file everytime then grep and cut might help you,

suppose you need value for css_source_folder property
prop1="css_source_folder"  (I am assuming you know property name whose value you want)

```
value_of_prop1=`grep $prop1 sample.conf| cut -f2 -d "=" | cut -f2 -d ">"`
```

like,

```
[db2inst2@pegdb2 ~]$ vi con.conf
[db2inst2@pegdb2 ~]$ grep css_source_folder con.conf
css_source_folder=>/home/d/g/h
[db2inst2@pegdb2 ~]$ value=`grep css_source_folder con.conf | cut -f2 -d "="`
[db2inst2@pegdb2 ~]$ echo $value
>/home/d/g/h
[db2inst2@pegdb2 ~]$ value=`grep css_source_folder con.conf | cut -f2 -d "=" | cut -f2 -d ">"`
[db2inst2@pegdb2 ~]$ echo $value
/home/d/g/h
```

If you want to read all properties at once, then apply loop and this will solve the purpose

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get the configuration names and values relatively simple and associate them through array indexes. Reading your config can be done like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

test -r "$1" || { echo "error: unable to read conf file [$1]\n"; exit 1; }

declare -a tag
declare -a data
let index=0

while read line || test -n "$line"; do

    tag[index]="${line%%\=*}"
    data[index]="${line##*\>}"
    ((index++))

done < "$1"

for ((i=0; i<${#tag[@]}; i++)); do

    printf " %18s   %s\n" "${tag[$i]}" "${data[$i]}"

done
```

After reading the config file, you then have the config name tags and config values stored in the arrays `tag` and `value`, respectively:

```
       pt_user_name   xxxx
          pt_passwd   Junly@2014
 jrnl_source_folder   x/y/v
   pt_source_folder   /x/y/r/g
  css_source_folder   /home/d/g/h
```

At that point, it is a matter of determining how you will use them, whether as a password or as a directory. You may have to write a couple of functions, but the basic function of given a tag, get the correct data can be done like this:

```
function getvalue {

    test -n "$1" || { echo "error in getvalue, no data supplied"; return 1; }

    for ((i=0; i<${#tag[@]}; i++)); do

        if test "$1" = "${tag[$i]}"; then
            echo " eval cmd ${data[$i]}"
            return $i
        fi

    done

    return -1
}

echo -e "\nget value for 'jrnl_source_folder'\n"

getvalue "jrnl_source_folder"
```

The function will return the index of the data value and can execute any command needed. You seem to have directory paths and passwords, so you may need a function for each. To illustrate, the output of the example is:

```
get value for jrnl_source_folder

eval cmd x/y/v
```

You can also use an associative array in later versions of BASH to store the tag and data in a single associative array. You may also be able to use `indirect references` on the tag and data values to process them. I simply took the straight forward approach in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `eval $(awk -F'=>' '{print $1"=\""$2"\";"}' sample.conf)`:

EX:

```
eval $(awk -F'=>' '{print $1"=\""$2"\";"}' sample.conf); echo $pt_user_name
xxxx
```

Using `sed` :

```
eval $(sed -re 's/=>/="/g' -e  's/$/";/g' sample.conf); echo $pt_passwd 
Junly@2014
```

Using `perl` :

```
eval $(perl -F'=>' -alne 'print "$F[0]=\"$F[1]\";"' sample.conf); echo $pt_source_folder
/x/y/r/g
```

Using `tr` :

```
eval $(tr -d '>' <sample.conf); echo "$css_source_folder"
/home/d/g/h
```

PS. Using `tr` blindly to remove `>` may cause undesirable results depending on the content of sample.conf, but for the one provided works fine.

Comment: Much less typing, I like that answer.

Comment: Thank Tiago. but i need it without awk